# Не могу применить миграции из-за .env файла

Tags: php, yii2, composer, openserver, .env

Проблема заключатся в том, что на свой yii2 проект установил `"vlucas/phpdotenv"` и указал все переменные для подключения к бд. Приложение работает и запросы выполняет но когда я пытаюсь создать или применить миграции пишет `Connection::dsn cannot be empty.`. Переменные получал как через `getenv()`, так и через `$_ENV[]`

Пробовал версии:

- `"vlucas/phpdotenv": ^5.3`
  В этой версии создавал через `(Dotenv\Dotenv::createUnsafeImmutable(dirname(__DIR__)))->load();`
  , иначе он возвращал false
- `"vlucas/phpdotenv": 2.0.0`
- `"symfony/dotenv"`

Работаю через OpenServer(Apache_2.4, PHP-7.4, MariaDB).
На сервере Ubuntu 20.04 nginx такая же проблема.

Comment: в консоли зачастую свой файл конфигурации, предполагаю там просто пропустили настройку когда указывали конфигам где брать переменные для подключения

Answer (score 1):

Как мне указали в [комментарии](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1320183/%d0%9d%d0%b5-%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%83-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bc%d0%b8%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d0%b7%d0%b0-env-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb%d0%b0/1328023#comment2335928_1320183), я не указал в файле @app/console/yii свои переменные.

При определении в Yii файле:

```
    require("Путь до файла где написано $dotenv = new \Dotenv\Dotenv(dirname(__DIR__));
    $dotenv->load(); ");
```

Миграции заработали.